# Unit testing $scope function which calls named functions that increment $scope vars

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a $scope function which calls private (named functions) inside of it. Within these named functions I increment a $scope.counter variable. When unit testing this it's going into my functions but is never actually incrementing $scope.counter (in the test, works in the app).

Is it possible to unit test that these are being incremented inside my named functions since they are not actually accessible from a unit test?

Comment: Please post your code, both the code you are trying to test and your unit test code. Generally, what you want to do (testing methods not accessible in the scope) is possible.

Comment: please share code sample... or create jsfiddle

Comment: Yes it's possible. Question answered :)